# phpMyAdmin - what' swrong with next configuration?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

tryin to install phpMyAdmin on my Fedora server, but if i open it in browser, i get next error:

2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

file config.inc.php have next content:

```
<?php

/* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '123';


/* End of servers configuration */

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '4c45c50fe8b283.01675296';
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en-utf-8';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
?>
```

just to add, in mysql i created user root, with password 123, so i can log in with:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p123
```

can you help me where is the problem?

Comment: Is `-p123` just a copy and paste typo? Should be `-p 123`

Comment: @DrColossos nope, that is actually the correct notation. `-p 123` won't work

Comment: hmm never used mysql shell... that was more of an obvious (unfortunately false :() guess, but thanks for correcting.

Comment: i want to say that password defined in config file is good. and that i need help how to connect to phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i solve it.

in configuration file, i just changed 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1', and it started to work.

tnx anw!

Comment: *doh* - Didn't see any "answers has been added" while I was editing mine. But yes, it's either (localhost & socket) or (127.0.0.1 & tcp) because of the reason specified above.  :)

Answer (score 4):

`mysql -h localhost` actually connects via [unix socket](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_socket) instead of a TCP connection to 127.0.0.1. Explicitly specifying `mysql -h 127.0.0.1` on the other hand *does* use the TCP method.

So what you are testing is a local socket connection, not a network one. Make sure phpMyAdmin uses the same method; the line

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
```

should probably read

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'socket';
```

---

Your mysqld probably has either [networking disabled](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-networking) or user permissions denying root/123 access from the network.

With `-h localhost` in your example you are actually connecting over a named socket. You can see for yourself - from the mysql client type "\s":

```
mysql> \s
--------------
(....)
Connection:     Localhost via UNIX socket
```

Comment: it's possible because i chroot-ed my server. i will check that also.